# How to appropriately apply styles to a functioning get request using JQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, ajax

So here's whats going on, I have a couple scenarios where I can't seem to apply any styles to content coming from a get request, and on one of them I managed to be able to but it wouldn't be considered best practice.

Premise:
I have an empty Ul to which Li's will be attached from a GET request to an API.

Scenarios

1) I create DOM objects using JQuery and append  LI <-- SPAN <-- string to the empty UL and then state that all the children of the UL will be colored green.
(this does not work & yes I could target the UL and have everything inherit the styles but that wont work for what I have in mind)

2) I append a string which contains HTML markup within it to then add styles and concat them with what the GET request spits out. ( for some reason it seems to work this way but I really don't want to be creating LI's and SPANS + classes all in one string)

```js
//scenario 1
var $orders = $("#orders");
$.ajax({

    type: 'GET',
    url: 'http://rest.learncode.academy/api/johnbob/friends',
    success: function (data) {
        $.each(data, function (i, item) {
            if (item.name && item.drink) {
                var $spn = $("<span></span>");
                var $lli = $("<li></li>");
               // $spn.append(String(item.name));
                $spn.css({width: "20px"});
                $orders.append($lli).append($spn).append("name: "+item.name+", Order: " + item.drink);
                $orders.children().css({ color: "green" });
                console.log($spn);
            }
            })
    }
});



/* scenario 2

var $orders = $("#orders");
$.ajax({

    type: 'GET',
    url: 'http://rest.learncode.academy/api/johnbob/friends',
    success: function (data) {
        $.each(data, function (i, item) {
            if (item.name && item.drink) {
                var $spn = $("<span>hell</span>");
                var $lli = $("<li></li>")
               // $spn.append(String(item.name));
                $spn.css({width: "20px"});
                $orders.append("<li>Name: <span class='tato'>" + item.name + ",</span> Order: " + item.drink + "</li>");
                $orders.children().css({ color: "green" });
                console.log($spn);
            }
            })
    }
});


*/
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<h2>Coffee Orders</h2>

                <br />
                <ul id="orders">
                  <li>control group</li>
                </ul>
                <br />

                <h4>Add a coffee order</h4>
                <p>name: <input type="text" id="name"></p>
                <p>drink: <input type="text" id="drink"></p>
                <button id="add_order">Add!</button>
```

I haven't been able to find a reliable answer as to why this is happening, eventually I'll want to line up the orders regardless of the name length using a span.

edit:
What was happening (as stated in the answer) was I was appending empty LI's SPANs and Strings to the original UL. When using     append()  keep in mind anything you add (in a chain form) will be appended to the original stated element and not the previous one.

Side note: 
For more information on better practice of templating incoming GET stuff check out this vid I found.
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=GbNWPn8vodo&index=9&list=PLoYCgNOIyGABdI2V8I_SWo22tFpgh2s6_

Comment: `span` is an inline element (therefor don't have width)

Comment: yes which is why I'm using color to determine it's effects.

Comment: you can't :) you can change it to `div` if you want

Comment: Please read the question carefully.

Comment: Is requirement to set `span` descendant of `li` `css` `color` to `green`?

Comment: You realize you are not appending anything to the li or the span, correct?  append() returns the element that it operates upon, not what was appended.

Comment: Hmm I did not, I'm used to appendChild, I'll fiddle with it to see if that was the issue.

Comment: no, it seems i was using it correctly.

Comment: @Noob5456 `<span>` element and `#text` node are not valid child elements of `<ul>` element at `html` `document`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As noted by @Taplar the issue is use of `.append()`. You are appending `<span>` elements and `#text` nodes to `<ul>` at

```
$orders.append($lli).append($spn).append("name: "+item.name+", Order: " + item.drink);
```

which are not valid child elements of [`<ul>`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/ul)

> Permitted content zero or more `<li>` elements, which in turn often
>   contain nested `<ol>` or `<ul>` elements.

To correct issue, set `#text` node as `.innerHTML` of  `<span>` element, and `span` element as `.innerHTML` of  `<li>`  element using `html` of `jQuery(html, attributes)` function `attributes` property.

Also set `span` `css` `display` property to `block` for `width` property to be applied to the element.

```js
//scenario 1
var $orders = $("#orders");
$.ajax({

  type: 'GET',
  url: 'http://rest.learncode.academy/api/johnbob/friends',
  success: function(data) {
    $.each(data, function(i, item) {
      if (item.name && item.drink) {
        var $spn = $("<span></span>", {
          html: "name: " 
                + item.name 
                + ", Order: " 
                + item.drink,
          css: {
            width: "20px",
            display: "block",
            position: "relative"
          }
        });
        var $lli = $("<li></li>", {
          html: $spn
        });
        $orders.append($lli)
          .children().css("color", "green");
      }
    })
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<h2>Coffee Orders</h2>

<br />
<ul id="orders">
  <li>control group</li>
</ul>
<br />

<h4>Add a coffee order</h4>
<p>name:
  <input type="text" id="name">
</p>
<p>drink:
  <input type="text" id="drink">
</p>
<button id="add_order">Add!</button>
```

Comment: Oh you got it! thank you, I had to append it separately, and it doesn't string together as I thought it would.